# код не работает не понимаю python aiogram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

> AttributeError: module 'aiogram.dispatcher' has no attribute 'message_handler'

вот сам код

```
from aiogram import Bot, dispatcher, executor, types

#bot

bot = Bot(token="************")
dp = dispatcher
@dp.message_handler
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Замените это

```
from aiogram import Bot, dispatcher, executor, types

bot = Bot(token="************")
dp = dispatcher
```

на это

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

bot = Bot(token="************")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
```